# Is there a way to disable Firefox addon in a specific site?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I see Facebook being very slow when I enable the Roboform addon. Is there a way to disable this addon when I'm on Facebook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an extension cannot be restricted by any means - this restriction has to be part of it. In other words, you have to ask its developers to either allow disabling it on some sites or (preferably) fix the performance issues.